# O365 CDN not loading master page assets

Tags: office-365, css, custom-masterpage, cdn

I have recently enabled the public cdn on a tenant however this is now causing sites to fail loading css resources.

I have ran the following PowerShell:

```
Set-SPOTenantCdnPolicy -CdnType Public -PolicyType IncludeFileExtensions -PolicyValue "CSS,PNG"
```

However I am still getting a 404 error for almost all assets:

[image: CDN 404 Error]

I have enabled the cdn as we recently created an spfx web part and wanted the assets to load from the cdn. However I am now finding this issue across multiple sites, I am aware that I can remove master page origin using:

```
Remove-SPOTenantCdnOrigin -CdnType Public -OriginUrl */MASTERPAGE
```

However I would rather resolve this and have it work as expected than remove the master page origin just for the sake of it.

Appreciate any advice that can be given.